# Scanner inputs messing up with the chat client

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a very simple console chat with a server and multiple clients using RMI, just for fun.

For the client a menu is shown and an input is expected. Meanwhile, there's a thread running in a loop listening for petitions.

If some other client wants to chat with this one, he will receive a notification and he has to decide whether to chat with this other client or not to. And here is the problem. The menu is waiting for an input, and now the notification is waiting for a different one. So we have two, but I just want to give a response to the second one, I want to ignore the first one and whatever input I type goes to the notification choice.

How can I "destroy" the first waiting input so the client can just respond to that notification?

Comment: I dislike splitting the input streams like this. There should be one stream that you read from.

Comment: Why? And how would I manage my situation with just one stream?

Comment: You mean you're reading all this from the console? Sounds like you need a GUI to me. Classic case for a modal dialog. The question has nothing whatsoever to do with RMI.

Comment: I don't need a GUI, I said it's really simple, the menu would work just fine. And it indeed has nothing to do RMI, my bad. But that didn't answer my question.

Comment: No, the menu won't work just fine, because you have a modal dialog requirement. Otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Ok, then I should do it differently. I'm curios anyway, is there any way to break the input stance?

Comment: I agree with @christopher in that one Scanner is all you need. Your code should not "wait for inputs" and then "process the inputs" - this only works if inputs come neatly ordered, and fails with multiple threads. You should instead write *event-driven* code: *when* input comes, it should be handled according to the *current state* of the application - which you do not know when you start to listen for it.

Comment: @user207421 you *can* write event-driven console code. The fact that GUIs are event-driven does not mean that you *need* a GUI for building an event-driven program. Hell, most servers are event-driven, and don't even have an interface (GUI or otherwise)...

Answer (score -1):

In order to "destroy" the Scanner that is waiting for input, `break;` the `while` loop. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    while(true){
      System.out.println("Type ':cwoc' to chat with another client!");
      Scanner check1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userInput1 = check1.nextLine();
      
      ////////////
      //Put your code of whatever you want here
      ////////////
      
      if (userInput1.equals(":cwoc")){//chat with other client (cwoc)
        break; // 'destroys'(breaks) client 1
      } else {
        continue;
      }
     
    }
    
      System.out.println("Type 'hello client 2' to say hi!");
      Scanner check2 = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userInput2 = check2.nextLine();
      
      ////////////
      //Second Client Code (It could also lead to a function)
      ////////////
      if (userInput2.equals("hello client 2")){
        System.out.println("Hi client 1!");
      } 
  }   
}
```

**Here is the output:**

[image: output]

As you can see in the output, client 1's AI is responding every time client 1 types something. After client 1 sends a request to chat with client 2(:cwoc), it `break;` the `while` loop that responds to client 1, and activates client 2's AI.

Comment: While this works, it is not a good idea. It is better to use a single scanner, but have access to some kind of object that can tell you what to do with the input depending on wether or not you have incoming chat requests.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, you could solve this with 2 threads; one would wait for incoming requests from the server (lets call it the `networkThread`), and the other would wait for input from the user (the `keyboardThread`). And you want the user's input to the `keyboardThread` to be interpreted differently if your `networkThread` thread just printed `There is an incoming chat from Fred, accept?` to the console. Your problem right now is (probably) that the code handling keyboard input does not know anything about incoming requests. Let us change this by adding another object which *does* know all that is going on:

```
public interface KeyboardListener {
     void handleInput(String input); // handle keyboard input
}

public interface NetworkListener {
     void handleChatRequest(Chat request); // handle incoming chat request
}

public class Controller implements KeyboardListener, NetworkListener {

     private Chat chat = null;          // currently active chat
     private boolean chatting = false;  // if true, chat is active

     void handleInput(String input) {
        synchronized (this) {
           if (chat != null) {
              if (chatting) {
                 chat.send(input);                     
              } else if (":accept".equals(input)) { 
                 chatting = true;
                 chat.send("Chat accepted!");
              } else if (":reject".equals(input)) {
                 chat.send("Chat rejected!");
                 chat.close();
                 chat = null;
              }
           } // ... many more states & commands can be handled here
        }
     }

     void handleChatRequest(Chat request) {
        synchronized (this) {
           System.out.println("Incoming request from " + request.name() 
              + " - write :accept to accept it, or :reject to reject it");
           if (chatting) {
              request.send("User is already chatting with someone else");
           } else {
              chat = request;
              request.send("Awaiting user to accept request");
           }
        }
     }

}
```

So you would just need to launch your `KeyboardThread` and `NetworkThread` which receive the *same* `Controller` object (but the `KeyboardThread` thinks it is a `KeyboardListener`, and the other thinks it is just a `NetworkListener`). Whenever each thread has something to say, it calls the corresponding `handleXxx` method of the controller - which knows what to do. The `synchronized` blocks are there just in case both threads try to call the handlers at the same time, which would otherwise cause a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) and potentially unexpected behavior.

Comment: This might work on some console IDE's, but it won't work on online IDE's like codiva.io.